# how to use `new` for pointer to array

Tags: c++

```
#define N 10
int (*p)[N] = new int[N];

// or

typedef int TenInts[N];
TenInts *p = new TenInts;
```

Is this something the C++ language simply disallows? Are there any workarounds? (except `std::vector` as all I need is a dynamically allocated array with known compile-time size)\

I need `new` as I'm putting the static array inside a template that uses `new`, and the template accepts a generic type `T`. Consider, `template<typename T> void f() {T *t = new T;}`, where I want `T` to be a static array.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: C++ arrays are just pointers to the first index

Comment: @m_callens I think no, if C++ is compatible enough with C.. and I think I know enough about C..

Comment: @KerrekSB Are there any workarounds? As I wrote there..

Comment: @MinjaeKim, no, in general C++ is not compatible with C, but the very opposite is true.

Comment: @KerrekSB I understand that my original question was a bit unclear; made an edit.

Comment: Can you please clarify (possibly with code) what do you mean with "I need new _as I'm putting the static array inside a template that uses new,_ and the template accepts a generic type T".

Comment: @Bob__ Yes, see my edit.

Comment: Hm, I'm still not sure a) what you want to achieve, and b) what is unclear to you. Could you describe what you think should happen and what precise error you are facing?

Comment: @KerrekSB Everything is clear if I put `std::array<...>` in place of `T` instead of a real array. I got this solution hinted from an answer, but the guy who gave that answer named πάντα ῥεῖ still isn't editing his/her answer to suit my question, so I cannot accept that answer.

Comment: Well, not so better... Is it something anywhere close to [this snippet](https://ideone.com/zZrUDH) that you have in mind or are you trying to wrap a class around an array?

Answer (score 1):

you want

```
int *p = new int[N];
```

you cannot specify at compile time a size for an array that you intend to dynamically allocate. Why would you do that anyway

Comment: dealing with templates.. trying to make them accept a static array.. `std::array` from the other answer seems to help.

Answer (score 1):

> as all I need is a dynamically allocated array with known compile-time size

You don't need to use `new` in that case.

Just use

```
#define N 10
std::array<int,N> p;
```

Comment: I need `new` as I'm putting the static array inside a template that uses `new`. Anyway your `std::array` helps.

Comment: I'll accept your answer if you edit your answer to use `new`.

Comment: I don't get why `new` is necessary (since `N` is known at compile time) can you elaborate about that requirement please?

Comment: The template takes a generic type `T`. Everything seems to be okay if `T` is `std::array<...>`. Please edit your answer as your answer did help.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use

```
int (*p)[N] = new int[N];
```

However, you can use:

```
int (*p)[N] = new int[1][N];
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you want.

```
#include <array>
constexpr size_t N = 10;
auto * ptr = new std::array<int, N>();
```

This allows you to create an array with compile-time constant size at runtime using `new`.

Edit: I'm assuming that, when you say "my template uses `new`", you mean `new` as opposed to `new[]`. This implies that your template eventually calls `delete` as opposed to `delete[]`.

Comment: Hmm, that's knd of weird IMO.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I agree

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
int (*p)[N] = new int[1][N];
```

or replace `1` by larger numbers if you want several rows.

Comment: You have been ninja'd by R Sahu.